Problem with 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' after upgrading to Flutter 3.27.1
After upgrading my Flutter project to version 3.27.1, I encountered the following issue:
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does 
exist.

Interestingly, if I remove the line importing 'package:flutter/foundation.dart', the issue goes away, and the project runs fine.
I'm wondering:

Why is this issue happening with the new Flutter version?
Is 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' deprecated or no longer necessary?
What would be the best practice for resolving this problem without potentially breaking anything in my project?

I tried searching for relevant documentation or changelogs but couldn't find a clear explanation.
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; // This causes the error

void main() {
    print('Hello, Flutter!');
}

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Here is a minimal example where the error occurs:

My editor removes unneeded imports on save.  You might consider that.
